# Scroll to top when going to next page of results in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

When using the Vuetify v-data-table element set to allow scrolling, is there a way or setting that would cause the results to scroll back to the top when clicking to the next page of results?  By default when you click to show the next 10 records after having scrolled down you have to manually scroll back up to start looking at record 11, etc.

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    fixed-header
    :height="height"
    :items="invoices"
    item-key="id"
    :search="search"
    class="elevation-1"
    :loading="loading"
    loading-text="Loading...please wait..."
    no-data-text="No invoices needing approval."
    no-results-text="No invoices found for your search."
>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use vuetify 2.0 you can try something like but this event also triggers when you change count per page:

```
<v-data-table
  ref="dataTable"
  @update:page="$vuetify.goTo($refs.dataTable)"
  ...
```

Comment: I'm using Vuetify 2.1.12. Code above does not seem to do anything. Still need the table to scroll back to the top.

Comment: Check here (with the lates version) https://codepen.io/ilearnjs/pen/ExaQPra?editors=1010

Comment: Look at this one where I have fixed header and a height:  https://codepen.io/cdecinko_knight/pen/ZEYrZKM?editors=1010

Comment: Ok. You can do something like here https://codepen.io/ilearnjs/pen/BayraKg?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

The following prop worked fine for me:

```
@update:page="$vuetify.goTo(0)"
```